Corda Token-SDK: How to query only received/incoming fungible tokens?
The Corda Token-SDK has a tokenBalance query utility function that returns the token balance of a specific token at the current time.
Is there a way to query only the from other parties received/incoming tokens of a specific token type between a specific time interval?
